# searchview oncloselistener not working

Tags: java, android

I need to have `oncloselistener` for my `searchview` in a menu, but `oncloselistener` is not working. I am not sure how to set `actionexpand` to my `searchview`.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("جستجو...");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: you haven't hooked up an functionality to onOptionsItemSelected, to set actionExpand do `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)`

Comment: i need expand listener @inner_class7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue last week! To my surprise, you don't set the listener to the `SearchView`, you actually set it to the menu item that expands it.
This is exactly what I had to do in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
        item = menu.findItem(R.id.friend_fragment_search_icon);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        // When using the support library, the setOnActionExpandListener() method is
// static and accepts the MenuItem object as an argument
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                //the searchview has been closed
                return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                mBtnFindFriends.hide();
                return true;  // Return true to expand action view
            }
        });
```

The friend_fragment_search_icon is the menu icon that opens the `SearchView`.
menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dingding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/friend_fragment_search_icon"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
        dingding:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        dingding:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```